# OpenGL - C++ VS 2013 nothing displayed, only black window

Tags: c++, opengl

This is exercises for my course in computer graphics, but I'm not asking for solutions, just for a way to be able to actually work on the exercises since right now I can't because all the output is producing is black window - I know what it's supposed to produce since I worked on it on school computers and am trying to work on it from home now.

The code works fine on school computers, and I've asked the TAs for help, but they've been unsuccesful so far in locating my problem.

The school computers run on VS 2010 windows 7, while I only have VS 2013 windows 8.1 available. When I opened the project the first time it asked me to convert it to VS2013 etc. and I did so.

I am able to run some other exercises just fine, but I have a problem with all exercises above 2.1.

The code below is from exercise 2.2

```
// 02561-02-02

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include "Angel.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Angel;

int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;

GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint projectionUniform,
    modelViewUniform,
    colorUniform;
GLuint positionAttribute;
GLuint unitCubeVertexArrayObject,
    axisVertexArrayObject,
    vertexBuffer;

const int axisSize = 6;

struct Vertex {
    vec4 position;
};

void loadShader();
void display();
GLuint loadBufferData(Vertex* vertices, int vertexCount);

void buildUnitCube() {
    const int cubeSize = 8;
    Vertex cubeData[cubeSize] = {
        { vec4( 1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4( 1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4( 1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4(-0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4(-0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4(-0.0,  1.0,  1.0, 1.0 ) },
        { vec4(-0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 1.0 ) }
    };
    unitCubeVertexArrayObject = loadBufferData(cubeData, cubeSize);
}

void buildAxis() {
    Vertex axisData[axisSize] = {
        {vec4(0., 0., 0., 1.0)}, // v0
        {vec4(4., 0., 0., 1.0)}, // vx
        {vec4(0., 4., 0., 1.0)}, // vy
        {vec4(0., 0., 4., 1.0)}, // vz
        {vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.0)}, // v0x1
        {vec4(1., 3., 0., 1.0)} // vyx1
    };
    axisVertexArrayObject = loadBufferData(axisData, axisSize);
}

GLuint loadBufferData(Vertex* vertices, int vertexCount) {
    GLuint vertexArrayObject;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *)0);

    return vertexArrayObject;
}

void loadShader(){
    shaderProgram = InitShader("const-shader.vert",  "const-shader.frag", "fragColor");
    projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
    if (projectionUniform == GL_INVALID_INDEX) {
        cerr << "Shader did not contain the 'projection' uniform."<<endl;
    }
    modelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modelView");
    if (modelViewUniform == GL_INVALID_INDEX) {
        cerr << "Shader did not contain the 'modelView' uniform."<<endl;
    }
    colorUniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    if (colorUniform == GL_INVALID_INDEX) {
        cerr << "Shader did not contain the 'color' uniform."<<endl;
    }
    positionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    if (positionAttribute == GL_INVALID_INDEX) {
        cerr << "Shader did not contain the 'position' attribute." << endl;
    }
}

void drawWireUnitCube() {
    GLuint indices[24] = {
        0,1,
        1,3,
        3,2,
        2,0,
        4,5,
        5,7,
        7,6,
        6,4,
        7,1,
        6,0,
        4,2,
        5,3
    };
    glBindVertexArray(unitCubeVertexArrayObject);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
}

void drawAxis() {
    GLuint indices[8] = {
        0,1,
        0,2,
        0,3,
        4,5
    };
    glBindVertexArray(axisVertexArrayObject);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 8, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
}

void display() {    
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    mat4 projection = Ortho(-6., 6., -6., 6., -6., 10.);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, projection);

    mat4 modelView(1.0f);

    vec4 red(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glUniform4fv(colorUniform, 1, red);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    drawAxis();

    // todo multiply model transformations 

    vec4 white(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glUniform4fv(colorUniform, 1, white);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniform, 1, GL_TRUE, modelView);
    drawWireUnitCube();



    glutSwapBuffers();

    Angel::CheckError();
}

void reshape(int W, int H) {
    WINDOW_WIDTH = W;
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = H;
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 2);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(
        GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
        GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow("02561-02-02");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutReshapeWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    Angel::InitOpenGL();


    loadShader();
    buildUnitCube();
    buildAxis();

    Angel::CheckError();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Try to change the clear color. Then you will see whether your objects are not drawn or if they are drawn in black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code requests a Core Profile context:

```
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

but it's not completely compatible with the Core Profile. In the Core Profile, all vertex data needs to be sourced from buffers. Passing client side arrays for vertex data is not supported anymore. This includes index data. So the following is not allowed:

```
GLuint indices[8] = {
    0,1,
    0,2,
    0,3,
    4,5
};
glBindVertexArray(axisVertexArrayObject);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 8, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

You need to store the indices in a `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Extend the signature of `loadBufferData()` function to also take index data, and add code to also create an index buffer:

```
GLuint loadBufferData(Vertex* vertices, int vertexCount
                      GLuint* indices, int indexCount) {
    ...

    GLuint indexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexCount * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    return vertexArrayObject;
}
```

Then the draw functions look like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(axisVertexArrayObject);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 8, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```